# home_url() возвращает адрес текущей страницы WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно получить адрес главной страницы и потом добавить туда дополнительный текст, например мне нужно получить ссылку:
*text.ru/project1/ssylka*, вордпресс установлен в директорию *text.ru/project1/*, для этого я пишу:

```
<? home_url().'/ssylka' ?>
```

Но если я сейчас нахожусь в *text.ru/project1/lol/kek/lol/kek*, то ссылка будет выглядеть как *text.ru/project1/lol/kek/lol/kek/ssylka*, то есть home_url() выводит просто текущий адрес, что я делаю не так? Я пробовал get_home_url(), site_url() - он выводит просто text.ru, то есть не ту директорию, где вордпресс.

Comment: Попробовал сначала объявить переменную `<? $home = home_url() ?>`, затем просто использовал так: `<?= $home.'/ssylka' ?>` В этом случае работает нормально. Но я думаю, что это костыль

Answer (score 0):

Ваша задача решается так:

```
<?= home_url('/ssylka'); ?>
```

Вот [документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/), согласно которой функция принимает два аргумента, первый из которых - строка, которая добавляется к окончанию ссылки

Comment: Это круто, пока сайт не переезжает в другую директорию

Comment: @РашенБеар что, по-вашему, должно случиться, когда сайт переедет?

Comment: Путь поменяется на /ssylka2

Comment: @РашенБеар вы сами это проверили или вам просто так кажется? На моей памяти за три года переездов сайтов на WP такого не случалось ни разу

Comment: т.е. когда сайт переезжает в другую поддиректорию - у Вас ни разу не менялась ссылка по которой он доступен?

Comment: разумеется, ни разу. Потому что при переезде сайта в админке в общих настройках указываются новые данные. Посмотрите исходники функций `site_url()` и `home_url()`, их различие только в том, что они получают данные из разных полей в БД - `get_option('siteurl')` и `get_option('home')` соответственно

Comment: Т.е. тут `home_url('/ssylka') ` строка "/ssylka" тоже подтянется из настроек сайта без вмешательства в код?

Comment: Я может вас неправильно понимаю, но работа функции банальна до безобразия: она забирает из БД значение (сохранённый url) и добавляет к нему строку, переданную в первом аргументе. Почему эта строка должна измениться при изменении адреса сайта? Вы же её однозначно определили в переданном параметре.